# Why didn't Harry repair Hogwarts after the Battle of Hogwarts?

Tags: harry-potter, wandlore

It is noted in canon that Harry repaired his wand after the Battle of Hogwarts.

While he had the wand, why didn't he repair the war-torn Hogwarts grounds? It seems like the least he could do after causing on the order of 50 deaths in a single night.

Comment: Repairing a wand and a small town are different things, not to mention that repairs like that would likely not be at the front of his mind.

Comment: Pfft. Tidying up is what [the servants](http://49.media.tumblr.com/59c46dcf5833767d545e8352be78cdf1/tumblr_mpm8gbSEan1sto76xo1_500.gif) are for.

Comment: @Richard very new-rich of you ;)

Comment: And while he was at it, he could have donated his galleon fortune to the families of all those died in the battle too, eh?

Comment: @NewAlexandria - very "I don't care about the servants so I don't want them to be able to earn their food" of you :)

Comment: There's a difference between seeing people as means to a task, and a part of your life.  I can't stand when I see someone set the tone for denigration of people based on their position.

Comment: I think it’s a huge temptation. But after repairing the castle, what would stop him from doing other great things? With the Elder Wand it would be so much easier. In the end he would keep the wand and get killed by the next Voldemort.

Answer (score 22):

He's a 17 year old not-graduated not-especially gifted wizard.

He simply doesn't have the knowledge of the spells needed to repair something as magically advanced as **Hogwarts**, which was created by the 4 Founders.

The wand he has doesn't have some magical built-in "repair" function - it merely gives his spells he CAN cast extra power. So a simple "Repairo" is within his capabilities... but repairing Hogwarts isn't, Deathstick or not.

Also, the largely-destroyed condition of the castle is mostly a film invention, for better visuals. While there was some damage, in the book the damage was not nearly as drastic, nor worth wasting Harry's time on.

Comment: Is there anything that suggests that the 4 Founders were witches/wizards with power that couldn't be emulated? If the normal wands could so easily destroy the castle, I suspect even a mediocre wizard could resurrect it.

Comment: No one wizard with a wand destroyed all of the portions of Hogwarts that were destroyed. If everyone at Hogwarts helped use their magic, they could probably succeed in repairing a lot of Hogwarts, but no one person was going to be able to do that by themselves, especially not Harry.

Answer (score 9):

This is quite clearly covered in both the novel and the film.

The wand is very very (very) dangerous and using it has led to the messy downfall of every wizard who's ever possessed it along with large numbers of civilian casualties. Since he just made a great big speech in front of the entire wizarding world that the wand he just won is *the* Elder Wand, **frivolously wandering around repairing things and daring every would-be Voldemort wannabe to challenge him for it would be a bad idea**.

Oh, and he's a bit tired too

> After a while, exhausted and drained, Harry found himself sitting on a
>   bench beside Luna.

---

In the book he decides to stuff it underground:

> **‘That wand’s more trouble than it’s worth,’** said Harry. **‘And quite
>   honestly,’** he turned away from the painted portraits, thinking now
>   only of the four-poster bed lying waiting for him in Gryffindor Tower,
>   and wondering whether Kreacher might bring him a sandwich there, **‘I’ve
>   had enough trouble for a lifetime.’**

and in the [film](http://www.scribd.com/doc/163084623/HARRY-POTTER-AND-THE-DEATHLY-HALLOWS-PART-2-by-screenplay-Steve-Kloves#scribd) he decides to snap it to prevent anyone else getting their grubby mitts on it:

> Hermione raises her hand and Ron stops, sees that her eyes are fixed on
>   Harry, who is staring at the wand, his concentration total. **She
>   studies his face for a long moment, and then -- as if coming to
>   understand something-- begins to nod.** As Harry peers down at his
>   hands, Ron and Hermione do as well, watching as he takes the ends of
>   the wand and...Snap

[image]

Comment: One of the few departures from the books that is a clear improvement.

Comment: But it isn't magically destroyed. Reparo would work in this case, and the Elder Wand would be back.