# Why didn't they use magic to fix Hogwarts in the last book?

Tags: harry-potter

In the sixth movie, at the house Slughorn was hiding in, there was a mess. Later Dumbledore used magic to clean it all up very fast. After Hogwarts was destroyed in the last book, why didn't all the teachers use magic to fix it? You could see Filch cleaning it up with a broom, even though Dumbldore had the Elder Wand (to clean up Slughorn's damage at his residence); a few wizards together could clean Hogwarts.

Comment: Related, possible dupe: [Why didn't Harry repair Hogwarts after the Battle of Hogwarts?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/112293/5184). DVK's answer goes into the extent of the destruction in the book.

Comment: Yeah, that's probably the closer dupe now that I think about it. I wouldn't object if a mod wants to open and re-close.

Comment: Dumbledore didn't have the Elder Wand when Hogwarts was destroyed—he was dead.

Comment: I disagree with this being a dupe. The other question quite specifically asks why **Harry** doesn't use the **Elder Wand** to repair the castle; this one asks why the teachers (and students, presumably) don't all pull together to repair the castle with collective magic. The answer to the former is given in the other question, while the answer to this question is that _they probably did_, we just don't see it.

Comment: Reopened since the Filch question is about *cleaning* of the castle, and the repair required after the Battle of Hogwarts is a whole different kettle of fish. Since there's some disagreement over whether or not this is a dupe of the question @phantom42 mentioned, I'll leave the decision on whether or not to re-close it up to the community.

Comment: So, you're suggesting Harry would want to help _Filch_?  The nemesis of all students?  And the particular subject of most of his fears around his nocturnal castle prowling? You'd have to be a lot older than 17 to have the maturity to overcome his basic instincts there.

Comment: Here's another go at it: To the students at Hogwarts, keeping their school and home-away-from-home clean and tidy is something that just happens.  They don't have to care about it any more than any millennial college graduate has to worry about cleaning his room in his parent's house.  It just happens.  And as far as the teachers go ... well, they're nice people and all, but setting up Christmas decorations and making sure the kids don't climb all over the armor in the halls is about the extent of their interest in the physical plant.  Cleaning up is for staff.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I think the point trying to be made was Dumbledore used the Elder Wand to clean up Slughorn's (temporary) place of residence. So it would have been easier for him.

Comment: Hogwarts is a castle where magic is instilled into the very foundation. It is almost as if the castle is alive itself. So it would take a lot more than a sweep of the Elder Wand to fix everything up. The four founders of Hogwarts were considered to be some of the greatest witches and wizards of all time. However, there is no evidence to show that Hogwarts wasn't fixed. It must have been done out of picture, as described by Au101's answer.

Comment: I think it's still a duplicate as close to the same question is already answered...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why didn't Harry repair Hogwarts after the Battle of Hogwarts?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/112293/why-didnt-harry-repair-hogwarts-after-the-battle-of-hogwarts)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Well, what makes you think they didn't? Presumably this happens off screen, in the way that you never see the characters getting haircuts, clipping their pets' toenails, or using the bathroom for its intended purpose.

After the battle everyone was exhausted and also relishing in just being alive and having won, and also mourning their losses. We see a bit of that, and then the touching closing up moment with Harry, Ron and Hermione and the chat with Dumbledore's portrait and then the book ends where it should.

We don't see them burying the dead and holding funerals, we don't see them going home, we don't see them repairing the castle and we don't see them replanting the lawn, because nobody cares, the book ends with the end of the battle. As it should.

As for, anyway, Slughorn's house, the situation is a little different as that was a manufactured mess and relatively small. The damage done to Hogwarts was vast and caused by dark and powerful magic. The repairs required would also have been much more extensive. Slughorn's house was the house of Muggles with a few of his personal effects. Hogwarts was imbued with ancient magic and had statues which could come to life, staircases which lead to different places on different days, enchanted boundaries and so on and so forth. I don't think simple charms would quite be enough to restore full functionality.